# GStreamer - MJPEG stream to file

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline, mjpeg

I have problem with saving `MJPEG` stream to file.
 When I stream `MJPEG` using such pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=thirdmovie640x360.mp4 ! decodebin2 name=dec \
    ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! queue ! avimux name=mux \
    ! udpsink host=192.168.0.2 port=5000
```

I am able to play this stream on my second machine using such pipeline:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5000 ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

However, how can I save such `MJPEG` stream to file (without transcoding!) which will be able to be played in some media player? Could you recommend some pipeline?

---

I found such pipeline to save output stream as matroska file:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 ! multipartdemux ! jpegparse ! jpegdec \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! matroskamux ! filesink location=output.mkv
```

How to change it to save mp4 file? Such pipeline:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 ! multipartdemux ! jpegparse ! jpegdec \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

does not work. Could you help me save it as mp4 contener (or avi contener) without transcoding MJPEG video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MJPEG is a codec which in simple terms means that there are is a series of jpeg images. These jpegs have to be stored in a container if you want to view them as a video. MP4 is a common container to store them in.

So you can mux the jpegenc output back to a mp4mux and store it in a file. Any decent media player should be able to play it back.

Comment: It looks like `mp4mux` doesn't allow to record MJPEG in MP4 file container. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276014/how-to-record-image-jpeg-mjpeg-within-mp4-container-with-gstreamer]

Comment: Yes it seems avi does support it though

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem. Here are piplines which I was looking for:

**Server**

```
gst-launch filesrc location=thirdmovie640x360.mp4 ! decodebin2 name=dec
! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! queue ! multipartmux
! udpsink host=192.168.0.4 port=5000
```

**Client**

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 ! multipartdemux ! image/jpeg, framerate=25/1 
! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc
! avimux ! filesink location=output.avi
```

Comment: good. Actually why do you decode and rencode. Why not simply feed to avimux directly from jpegparse?